# JavaFX Lazy Loading in a ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, lazy-loading

I am trying to develop a JavaFX UI which is updated in real-time via a socket connection and receives thumbnails and thumbnail metadata.

The UI layout is laid out in the following way:

- Parent ScrollPane
- VBox child of Scrollpane
- HBox (Show image name for set of thumbnails) followed by a FlowPane containing the thumbnails for the image

I am trying to implement a lazy load which will help me increase the performance of the application as it slows down to a crawl once the UI receives about 1000 thumbnails.

There are two approaches that I am thinking would work but I need someone with better understanding and experience with JavaFX to help me make an informed decision:

1. Change the UI from having a Scrollpane VBox combo to a ListView with ListCells containing the HBox and FlowPane within them and then lazy loading them.
2. Implement a lazy loading with the same UI by checking the viewport bounds of the ScrollPane and loading only the elements visible in the viewport (or around it).

Please let me know if there are any better approaches to my problem.

Comment: https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html (It'll probably replace the items in the cells rather often so you should probably cache the images somewhere)

Comment: Try using `ListView` to take advantage of cell caching